# Get absolute position in frame

Tags: emacs

The way I understand how emacs displays stuff is that essentially everything is text. If you have something in the fringe or linum mode active, essentially your document is pushed a little inwards and something is written in the first few columns.

I'm writing a function for putting some stuff into the `head-line` and this works nicely, however, I would like the start of the text to be aligned with the start of the document.

Thus I am looking for a way to get the number of columns that sit between the frame border and the start of the *actual* document.

Let me illustrate using a poorly produced graphic:

[image: DistanceMarker]

I want to get the number of columns (or the number of pixels) that make up the distance marker by the ruler just below the line number `10000`.

The function which returns this value shall be executed in the functions which create the `head-line`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called `window-inside-edges` that you can use to determine the offset of the text area ("window body") from the total width and height of the window in columns and lines, respectively.

It returns a list four values; the order is left - top - right - bottom, so to get the value you are interested in for the current window, just do

```
(car (window-inside-edges))
```

More information on window coordinates can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coordinates-and-Windows.html); [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html) has information about window sizes, including a nice ASCII representation of window elements.

Comment: This does perfectly what I want! However, now I discovered a different problem: Not every column has the same width. I have determined the excess number of pixels, do you know how to insert a space that is `n` pixels wide? (For reference: You can find the pixel-wise dimensions using the `window-inside-pixel-edges` function)

Comment: @elemakil Off the top of my head I don't, unfortunately. However, this might help you: [Pixel Specification for Spaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pixel-Specification.html).